# Which kubectl should I use on macOS?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl, minikube

On macOS there's Docker Desktop which comes with a kubectl, there's the Homebrew kubectl, then there's the gcloud kubectl.

I'm looking to use Minikube for local Kubernetes development and also GKE for production.

Which kubectl should I use? I'm thoroughly confused by all the various versions and how they differ from one another. Does it matter at all other than the version of the binary?

Comment: Minikube also has [Kubectl built in](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/kubectl/).

Comment: @timsmelik: So many options :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't really matter from where you get an executable as long as it is a trusted source. Although you have to use a supported version ([documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/release/version-skew-policy/#kubectl)):

> kubectl is supported within one minor version (older or newer) of kube-apiserver.
>
> Example:
>
> kube-apiserver is at 1.20
> kubectl is supported at 1.21, 1.20, and 1.19